# c# Wait until co routine is finished before executing code

Tags: c#, php, mysql, unity-game-engine

Hi im trying to implement saving/loading from sql database into my game.
i have it all working apart from the fact that i need to hit load twice for it to load the data.

the code to set the data finishes before i have a chance to set it.

```
public void loadData()
{
    GetComponent<SavingLoading>().Load(GameObject.Find("LoginSystem").GetComponent<LoginSystem>().Username);

    if (GetComponent<SavingLoading>().LoadedData != "")
    {
        string[] Data = GetComponent<SavingLoading>().LoadedData.Split(',');

        Level = Convert.ToInt32(Data[0]);
        CurrentXp = Convert.ToInt32(Data[1]);
        currentHealth = Convert.ToInt32(Data[2]);
        maxHealth = Convert.ToInt32(Data[3]);

        Vector3 LoadedPos = new Vector3(Convert.ToSingle(Data[4]), Convert.ToSingle(Data[5]), Convert.ToSingle(Data[6]));
        transform.position = LoadedPos;
    }
}
```

Theese functions are in another script.

```
public void Load(string name)
{
    StartCoroutine(LoadCall(name));
}



IEnumerator LoadCall(string name)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("name", name);

    WWW www = new WWW(LoadPhP, form);
    yield return www;
    string _return = www.text;
    LoadedData = _return;
}
```

how can i go about only updating the data if there is data present? without having to press the load button twice.

Comment: You want to wait until after the coroutine finishes? Put that code inside the coroutine or add a callback function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html), you should wrap the www variable in a using statement in order to properly disposeit. Then yield return on it, like so:

```
using (WWW www = new WWW(url))
{
    yield return www;
    string _return = www.text;
    LoadedData = _return;
}
```

I am not sure what you mean by 'only updating the data if there is data present'. Do you have more code to show that might help to clarify your intent?

Comment: While potentially accurate, this doesn't actually answer their question.